# Window7 microsoft reportviewer choose printer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have program which execute on window XP and use microsoft reportViewer, all work fine and customers succeed print documents.

Where program run on Windows 7, when click on print button of control reportViewer do nothing. Expect show available printers in computers, but do nothing.

I think that problem relation on PrintDialog and property UseEXDialog = true, but in control not have option change that.

I compiled project in visual studio 2012, install windows reportviewer redistributable 2012 but problem not resolve.

Any idea to resolve problem.
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is resolved :)

When debug program see follow error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Message: External component has thrown an exception.

Source: System.Windows.Forms

Target site: Int32 PrintDlgEx(PRINTDLGEX)

This error occurs only Windows7. When search in google found next description “you program have the [STAThread] attribute specified”.

Code which set thread apartment state to ApartmentState.STA work fine.

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);